# ActionScript HTML Regexp Selector

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, html-parsing, exec, selector

I am *really* bad when it comes to using regexp, so please bear with me on this one.

I have piece of ActionScript code which is supposed to evaluate a string of HTML and break it up into individual pieces. So a string like `<p>Hi</p><span>Hi</span><a href="index.php">Hi</a>` would be translated into:

```
1. <p>Hi</p>
2. <span>Hi</span>
3. <a href="index.php">Hi</a>
...
```

However, when I run a test version of this code, I get a value of *null* in return. I'm pretty sure my regexp string is good, but I'm doing something wrong in ActionScript. Could you please point in the right direction? My code is below:

```
var evaluatedInput:RegExp = new RegExp('/<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>/');
var output:Object = evaluatedInput.exec("<p>Hi</p><span>Hi</span><a href=\"index.php\">Hi</a>");
trace(output);
```

Thank you for your time,
spryno724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ActionScript you're supposed to create a RegExp object one of two ways.  You can enclose the expression in `/.../` delimiters to form a regex literal:

```
/<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>/gi
```

...or you can write it as a *string* literal, which you pass to the the RegExp constructor:

```
new RegExp('<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\\1>', 'gi')
```

You seem to be using an amalgam of the two methods and getting garbage as a result.  Some other points of interest:

- Because regex literals use forward-slash as the delimiter, any `/` in the regex itself needs to be escaped with a backslash, e.g., `<\/\1>`
- In the string version it's the *backslash* you have to escape (e.g., `</\\1>`).  Otherwise the AS compiler tries to treat it as part a string-literal escape sequence like `\"` or `\n`.  In your code, the `\b` represents a backspace, not a word boundary, and `\1` is probably treated as a syntax error, not a back-reference as you intended.
- Your regex needs both the `g` ("global") and `i` ("ignore-case") modifiers; I've demonstrated how to apply them.

Comment: Wow, thanks Alan. I'm getting closer, but, due to my poor regexp understanding, I'm not _quite_ there. Using your regexp selector, I'm getting the following output `<p>Hi</p>,p,Hi`. It is possible to get only `<p>Hi!</p>,<span>Hi</span>,<a href="index.php">Hi</a>` and not just the tag or tag contents?

Comment: Never mind, I got it! Thanks for fixing the regexp and for the good explanation!

Answer (score 1):

**Example Usage**

Adapted from here
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html#exec()

```
     var myPattern:RegExp = /\>\</g;  
     var str:String = "<p>Hi</p><span>Hi</span><a href=\"index.php\">Hi</a>";
     var result:Object = myPattern.exec(str);

     //To loop through all results manually
     while (result != null) {             
         trace ( result.index, "\t", result);            
         result = myPattern.exec(str);
     }

     //or, just replace. Note this does not required the myPattern.exec(str);
     str.replace(myPattern, ">\n<");
```

**Original Answer**

See this answer:

[AS3 RegEx returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702436/as3-regex-returns-null/5702515#5702515)

At the very least, the tool from gSkinner should be a solution to your issue(s).

Specifically, to do what you want to do, you would use the following regex expression:

```
/\>\</g
```

And on your matches, use the index value, and replace with:

```
>\n<
```

You can test this yourself on the gskinner Regexr tool using the Replace tab.

Comment: Thank your for your help, but my regexp skills are so poor right now that I am having a hard time following you. Could you post a corrected version of the ActionScript regexp selector I posted above?

Comment: Hmm... thanks for the update, but I tried your example and it didn't return anything. :(

Comment: Sorry wasn't done. Fully updated, should work fine. I've tested, works as expected.

Comment: `<` and `>` have no special meaning in AS3 regexes (or in most other flavors, either).  But in some flavors, `\<` and `\>` *do* have special meanings (i.e., word boundaries), so it's best not to escape them.

Comment: Thanks Alan, you're right... although escaping them doesn't hurt either. :)

Comment: With the addition of the other post, I was able to get this working perfectly. Thanks for the example and the web link!